# Reading a text file and plotting it in 3D

Tags: matlab, 3d

I want to read in a text file that contains some strings but mostly numbers. I want to be able to ignore the strings and only look at the numbers. I want to plot those values on a 3D plane. The data looks like this:

```
Tech4:<152.266724,173.189377,27.995975> 
<117.880638,156.116531,27.999983> 
<129.849899,59.195660,27.999983> 
<249.321121,60.605404,27.999983>  
<224.120361,139.072739,28.000668> 
<171.188950,143.490921,56.933430> 
<171.188950,143.490921,83.548088>
<171.188950,143.490921,27.999985>
```

I believe to read in a file is just:

```
File = textread('testFile.txt');
```

How can I only look at those values and then plot it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
fid = fopen([pathname,filename]);

tline = fgetl(fid);

CX = [];
CY = [];
CZ = [];

while ischar(tline)
    % skip < and >
    tline = substr(tline, 1, length(tline)-2)

    % extract numbers
    temp = textscan(tline,'%n%n%n', 'delimiter',',');

    CX(end+1,:) = [temp(1)];
    CY(end+1,:) = [temp(2)];
    CZ(end+1,:) = [temp(3)];

    tline = fgetl(fid);
end

fclose(fid);
```

and then plot it using 
    plot3(CX, CY, CZ)

function call.

Add the check for "Tech4:" at the beginning however...

Comment: what is temp doing ('%n%n%n', 'delimiter',',')

Comment: temp is an array with a value triple extracted from string in N,N,N format. It is like sscanf(tline, "%f,%f,%f", &temp[0], &temp[1], temp[2]) in C.

Comment: It's saying CX,CY,CZ all change values on every loop.

Comment: the code above collects all the values into three arrays - CX, CY, CZ.

Comment: What's wrong with the line tline = fgetl(fid)? There's an error saying Invalid file identifier.  Use fopen to generate a valid
file identifier.

Comment: Sorry, Andre. I don't know what's wrong because I don't know what filename and pathname are you using. Maybe the file is just not found

Comment: lol I was saying fileTest not testFile.. but the line tline = substr(tline, 1, strlen(tline)-2); isn't working because "strlen' is of type "char"

Comment: Yes, change 'strlen' to 'length'

Comment: I believe there's more than enough information for you to complete the task. Try to understand, I do not have unlimited time to cover all of you needs. Good luck with this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can also directly use [textscan](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html) in a one-liner:

<s>fid = fopen('testFile.txt');

data = textscan(fid,'%*s%f,%f,%f');

fclose(fid);</s>

this loads the values from all rows with the specified format into the variable `data`.
no matlab around to test it out though.

[fscanf](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/fscanf.html) is an option to, the same kind of parameters as textscan.

**EDIT**: typo, you want to detect floats (%f) of course, and not integers (%d)


**EDIT2**: got matlab and tested it out, this works here for your sample input ^^

```
fid = fopen('testFile.txt');
data = textscan(fid,'%*s%f%f%f','Delimiter',',<>')
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: When I use fid = fopen([pathname, filename]), what do I put in for pathname for say something that's in c:/Program Files(x86)/Notepad++/fileTest.txt?

Comment: just use `fid = fopen('c:/Program Files(x86)/Notepad++/fileTest.txt');`